# React - Populating First Select Option with Redux State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, get, codesandbox

I have component `League.js` where there are 4 boxes containing League team details.

The team details are coming from this API => `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/league/${id}`

When I click on each of the league boxes I am populating the Dropdown in my component `Details.js`

I won't get the `team_id` of the **first team** in the dropdown anytime I click on each of the League boxes in `League.js` in order to have the right calculation in a component called `Stat.js`. To do this I make a call request to this endpoint => `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/${league}/${team}`

So I need to pass `league_id` and `team_id` as a parameter, I can get both values correctly but I am doing something wrong on how to pass the first `team_id` of the team for each league.

These are the steps, I put only the relevant code. I am creating `firstTeamStats` state that I am dispatching

**In my actions => index.js**

```
export const RECEIVE_FIRST_TEAM_STATS = "RECEIVE_FIRST_TEAM_STATS";

export const receivedFirstTeamStats = json => ({
  type: RECEIVE_FIRST_TEAM_STATS,
  json: json
});



.get(`https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/teams/league/${id}`)
.then(res => {
  let teams = res.data.api.teams;
  dispatch(receivedFirstTeamStats(teams[0].team_id));
})
```

**in my `reducer => index.js`**

```
case RECEIVE_FIRST_TEAM_STATS:
  return {
    ...state,
    firstTeamStats: action.json,
    isTeamsDetailLoading: false
  };
```

**in my League.js component**

```
import {getTeamsStats} from "../actions";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  firstTeamStats: state.firstTeamStats
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getStats: getTeamsStats,
};

const onClick = (evt, id, firstTeamStats) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  getDetail(id); \\  get the team names in the Detail.js component
  getStats(id, firstTeamStats); \\ get the state value for the first team in the dropdown in Detail.js component
};

<a href={`#${item.league_id}`} onClick={(e) => onClick(e, item.league_id, firstTeamStats)}
```

Right now `firstTeamStats` in the `onclick` method above returns correctly the first team state value but of the existing league and not in the one where I click which is what I want.

However I can get this correctly in the `Details.js` Component, I have put `{firstTeamStats}` there in the demo where I have reproduced my case => https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-solomon-6e0sb (Use CORS Unblock Chrome extension to see )

So the question is, how can i pass `{firstTeamStats}`  correctly in `League.js` in the method `onclick` to the request `getStats(id, firstTeamStats)` where `{firstTeamStats}` is the state of my first `team_id` of the league?

Comment: codesandbox is not working @koala

Comment: Use CORS Unblock Chrome extension to see

Comment: @Koala7.. i have posted my answer below. Do check and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are making an API call, it is an asynchronous event. You should always await, before using its response in the next line.

So inside `getDetail()`, you are making an API call. But you haven't declared this method as async. so you are not waiting for it to complete and in the next line you are calling `getStats()` method with an old data. Thats why your app will always be a step behind, than your DOM events.

- One way would be to use `async|await` and return the API response
  from the function, instead of using dispatch.
- You can also invoke the `getTeamsStats()` inside the `getTeamsDetailById()` after the api response is fetched, instead of invoking it inside `OnClick()`
  event.

`const onClick = (evt, id, firstTeamStats) => {
          evt.preventDefault();
          getDetail(id); \\  this is an async api call. you should have used await here.
          getStats(id, firstTeamStats); \\ It will execute before the new stats are fetched
        };`

In Stats.js, you should not be strictly validating these fields to show Statistics... these are only numbers.. can also be **0** at times. so please remove these checks.

```
if (
     teamsStatsWinHome &&
     teamsStatsWinAway &&
     teamsStatsDrawHome &&
     teamsStatsDrawAway &&
     teamsStatsLoseHome &&
     teamsStatsLoseAway
   ) {
```

I have a working instance of your application... check below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dewdney-zke2t

Let me know, if you need anything.